# Material-Ui how to change default color of textfields/inputs/labels when focused?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In the new (v1 beta) version of Material UI the default light theme was changed to purple/green from light-blue/pink.

When Text-Fields gain focus in this new version, their labal/input-line are colored in with the default purple.

I created my custom theme and overwrote the primary color, such that the buttons are now blue, but the labels/input-line are still purple.

How would I go about changing their default colors as well?

Answer (score 1):

This is a little bit tricky but once you understand how it works and how you can play with it, things become simple. I spent 15-20 minutes figuring it out using Chrome Developer Tools and here is the solution:

When the field is focused, it adds a new class MuiFormLabel-focused to the root.

It means that we have a focused property in the MuiFormLabel component. The problem is the precedence of the class is high as it is more specific and simply changing color will not work.

[image]

Since I was absolutely certain that I've to use my own color, I used !important.

[image]

Hope it helps.